# How to find the nearest above sibling <li> for each <li class=""><a>?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

My example html is

```
<li><h4>A0: Pronouns</h4></li>
<li class="">
    <a>bb</a>
    <a>cc</a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a>dd</a>
    <a>ee</a>
</li>
<li><h4>A0: Verbs Tenses & Conjugation</h4></li>
<li class="">
    <a>ff</a>
    <a>gg</a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a>hh</a>
    <a>kk</a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a>jj</a>
    <a>ii</a>
</li>
```

For each element `<li class=""><a>`, I would like to find its nearest above sibling `<li><h4>`. For example,

- `<li class=""><a>bb</a></li>` corresponds to `<li><h4>A0: Pronouns</h4></li>`.
- `<li class=""><a>dd</a></li>` corresponds to `<li><h4>A0: Pronouns</h4></li>`.
- `<li class="">ff<a>dd</a></li>` corresponds to `<li><h4>A0: Verbs Tenses & Conjugation</h4></li>`.
- `<li class="">hh<a>dd</a></li>` corresponds to `<li><h4>A0: Verbs Tenses & Conjugation</h4></li>`.
- `<li class="">jj<a>dd</a></li>` corresponds to `<li><h4>A0: Verbs Tenses & Conjugation</h4></li>`.

Could you please elaborate how to do so?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

link = 'https://french.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar'
r = session.get(link, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for d in soup.select('.callout-body > ul li > a:nth-of-type(1)'):
    print(d)
```

Comment: What do you have trouble with exactly? Accessing a `previous_sibling` of an element? Finding which one of those is an `li` with an `h4` as its first child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find_previous('h4')`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://french.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
for a in soup.select(".callout  li > a:nth-of-type(1)"):
    print(
        "{:<70} {}".format(
            a.get_text(strip=True), a.find_previous("h4").get_text(strip=True)
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Saying your name: Je m'appelle, Tu t'appelles, Vous vous appelez       A0: Pronouns
Tu and vous are used for three types of you                            A0: Pronouns
Je becomes j' with verbs beginning with a vowel (elision)              A0: Verbs Tenses & Conjugation
J'habite à [city] = I live in [city]                                   A0: Idioms, Idiomatic Usage, and Structures
Je viens de + [city] = I'm from + [city]                               A0: Idioms, Idiomatic Usage, and Structures
Conjugate être (je suis, tu es, vous êtes) in Le Présent (present tense) A0: Verbs Tenses & Conjugation
Make most adjectives feminine by adding -e                             A0: Adjectives & Adverbs
Nationalities differ depending on whether you're a man or a woman (adjectives) A0: Adjectives & Adverbs
Conjugate avoir (j'ai, tu as, vous avez) in Le Présent (present tense) A0: Verbs Tenses & Conjugation
Using un, une to say "a" (indefinite articles)                         A0: Nouns & Articles

...

French vocabulary and grammar lists by theme                           C1: Idioms, Idiomatic Usage, and Structures
French Fill-in-the-Blanks Tests                                        C1: Idioms, Idiomatic Usage, and Structures
```

Comment: Besides the elegance of your code (as always ^^), I really appreciate your dedication in formatting such a pretty output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:is` in your CSS path:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from collections import defaultdict
d, l = defaultdict(list), None
for i in soup1.select('li > :is(a, h4):nth-of-type(1)'):
   if i.name == 'h4':
      l = i.get_text(strip=True)
   else:
      d[l].append(i.get_text(strip=True))

print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'A0: Pronouns': ['bb', 'dd'], 'A0: Verbs Tenses & Conjugation': ['ff', 'hh', 'jj']}
```

The output is storing the first `a` for every `li` associated with a grammatical section. If you only want a `1-1` section to component result, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
new_d = {a:b for a, (b, *_) in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'A0: Pronouns': 'bb', 'A0: Verbs Tenses & Conjugation': 'ff'}
```

Comment: Your  compact output (a dict) is interesting. Actually, I only want the *first*  `<a>` of each `<li class="">`. That's why I use `a:nth-of-type(1)`. Can you modify your code to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed update :v